# jQuery UI styled text input box

Tags: css, jquery-ui, user-interface

jQuery UI makes buttons look nice with `$('button').button();`.

Is there an equivalent for text input boxes?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There's nothing to stop you from doing `$("input").button()`... I like this:

```
$('input:text, input:password')
  .button()
  .css({
          'font' : 'inherit',
         'color' : 'inherit',
    'text-align' : 'left',
       'outline' : 'none',
        'cursor' : 'text'
  });
```

[A fuller example.](http://jsfiddle.net/corin/UXdLQ/4/)

Comment: .button() gives you (1) alot of css; and (2) hover/focus/blur event handlers.

Of course, you can use .button().addClass('my-textfield') and add the css to a stylesheet... Here's a fuller example for you: [jsfiddle.net/UXdLQ](http://jsfiddle.net/UXdLQ/1/)

Comment: Also, you may want to remove the 'mousedown' event to stop it from adding the 'ui-state-active' class (which turns the text box white) when you click on the text box. With jQuery >= 1.7, you can do this with `.off('mousedown')`.

Comment: @Corin - Looks nice, but when I scale down the button size to `height:10px`, Firefox clips the top and bottom of the text.

Comment: You may also need to remove "keydown" as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18835405/477420

Comment: Rather than turning off all the button() behaviour, I prefer the answer below where you simply add the jQuery UI styling classes - `$('#thing').addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-button");` - and maybe throw in `ui-state-default` to set the background fill to be button-like.

Answer (score 22):

Add the class `ui-corner-all` to your input and post-style the input with CSS.

```
$('input').addClass("ui-corner-all");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TTShr/

Comment: +1 This works well. It does more than just make the corners round.

Answer (score 19):

I know this is old. But, if anyone is just looking to style their inputs to look more UIish, just add the following classes: `$('input').addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all");`

You could just hard code the classes too.

Comment: This is probably the easiest way to go, clear and maintainable.

Answer (score 6):

To sum things up I would like to add my implementation:

```
$('input:text, input:password, input[type=email]').button()
  .addClass('ui-textfield')
  .off('mouseenter').off('mousedown').off('keydown');
```

The CSS would be:

```
.ui-textfield {
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    background: none;
    text-align: inherit;
    outline: none;
    cursor: text;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/UXdLQ/1544/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I came up with the following solution. Use these classes on your input field:

`ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all`

You may modify the padding - f.e. if you `select` elements on your site - to be unified.

jQuery UI v1.11.4

Answer (score 2):

also add a `.off('keydown')` to **Corin's** answer to prevent the box from turning white when enter or space is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The example in your question cites jQuery UI's Button widget. The idea of this widget is to have a range of options including ease of theme-ing. There is a widget for input boxes too. Some of them that I'm aware of are as below:

1. [Auto-Complete Widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
2. [Default Text Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dText) for input-box
3. [Text Limit Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/textLimit) for input-box / text-area

There are many such plugins if not for widgets. You can always browse/search through at the search box available in the page http://plugins.jquery.com/

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I want more **style**, as I find the standard input boxed horrible. Thanks though.

Comment: Hmmm..so you want to add styling to input box which should be part of some form. Then why not look at form-styling plugins that some of jQuery plugins are meant for. You may look at http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2009/09/50-jquery-plugins-for-form-enhancements.html, and http://forum.jquery.com/topic/styling-form-input-elements

Answer (score 1):

I liked the idea of simply adding the classes so much I wrote it as a jQuery plugin. Benifit here is if at some poitn in the future jQueryUI do a version it will most likely use the same format, so converting will be easy.

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.input = function ()
    {
        return this.each(function ()
        {
            $(this).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-button");
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Call it like:

```
$('input, password').input();
```

If you wanted to add hover effects etc, just add the logic into

```
return this.each(function ()
{
    // display logic
});
```

EDIT:
Added in additional class "ui-button" to make them the same height / padding etc as .button()

EDIT 2:
This turned out to be such a good idea I've carried on, adding a version for labels, and allowing custom CSS to be passed in.

```
// some styling for inputs
(function($)
{
    $.fn.input = function (css)
    {
        if (!css)
            css = {};
        return this.each(function ()
        {
            $(this).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-button");
            $(this).css(css);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
// and labels
(function ($)
{
    $.fn.label = function (css)
    {
        if (!css)
            css = {};
        return this.each(function ()
        {
            $(this).addClass("ui-widget ui-button");
            $(this).css(css);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then too style your inputs / labels. The class / styles of these don't actually need to exist anywhere.

```
$(".client-input").input();
$(".client-label").label({ "min-width": "125px", "text-align": "right" });
```

Outputs UI like this - with inputs and labels matching the style of the button. (Select's need work)

[image]

Comment: You can also change "ui-widget-content" to "ui-state-default" to give it the same background fill as a button. Or just add "ui-state-default" since it overrides in the way you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

To have the same corners/font/padding/spacing as button, but without the button interactions (hover, active etc.)

HTML:
    input type="text" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all"

if you want to align text add another custom class

CSS:
    .textfield { text-align:left; }

HTML:
    input type="text" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all textfield"