# Do Bootstrap/jQueryUI have control label+textbox combined?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I know there are Bootstrap's styled [forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), with nice rounded corners and placeholder text. There are also [some classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802085/jquery-ui-styled-text-input-box) you can add to element surrounding other elements, to set the same border as other controls in your colored jQuery-UI css theme. Yet oddly enough there doesn't seem to be a standard control with both the label *and the* input within a bordered box.

Naturally this should be easy with css, and I know how to do that - but I'm wondering if I'm missing something as to how to create a textbox *with a label inside* its box, in Bootstrap or preferably jQueryUI - seems this would be a fairly common use case.

Comment: Why don't you just use a placeholder? It's supported by most mayor browsers and is independent of both jQuery and Bootstrap. More info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: either you're looking for placeholder attribute, else http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups. I can't think of anything else unless you come up with an image or something of a specific design showing a common use case  apart from these wo